# ModSecurity: No action id present within the rule

Tags: apache, mod-security

[root@vmn-ssd-42 ~]# httpd -t
Syntax error on line 17 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_security.conf:
ModSecurity: No action id present within the rule

```
SecRuleEngine On
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "text/xml" \
    "id:'200000',phase:1,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=XML"
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "multipart/form-data" \
    "chain,phase:2,t:none,t:lowercase,deny,msg:'ModSecurity DoS attempt - NULL part header name'"
```

Comment: please suggest to fix this.

Comment: Which one is line 17?

Answer (score 4):

Since [ModSecurity 2.7 the id attribute is mandatory](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#id). Your second rule does not contain an id.

Change it from this:

```
 SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "multipart/form-data" \
"chain,phase:2,t:none,t:lowercase,deny,msg:'ModSecurity DoS attempt - NULL part header name'"
```

To this (assuming rule id 200001 is not used elsewhere):

```
 SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "multipart/form-data" \
"id:'200001', chain,phase:2,t:none,t:lowercase,deny,msg:'ModSecurity DoS attempt - NULL part header name'"
```